# How to replace home page in Azure Function App with something else?

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

Using application setting `"AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage": true` the default home page for an Azure Function App is disabled, but how can I replace this page with something else?

For example, having a function that returns an HTML page:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
import { promises as fs } from "fs"
import { resolve } from "path"

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    const htmlPage = await fs.readFile(resolve(__dirname, "../../index.html"), "utf-8")

    context.res = {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "text/html"
        },
        body: htmlPage
    }
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

Setting `"routePrefix": ""` in `host.json` I should be able to serve this function from any route:

```
"extensions": {
  "http": {
    "routePrefix": ""
  }
}
```

But I just can't serve it from `/`, it always returns an empty page. Is there any way to overwrite this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround I did to replace the default home page of the Azure Functions (typeScript Stack - Http Trigger) with an HTML Page.

- Firstly, Created the Azure Functions in typeScript with Http Trigger using VS Code.
- Created the HTML File with some code under the Http Trigger Directory:
  [image: HTML Code in Azure Function]
- and here is the folder structure:

  [image: FolderStructure]
- In `local.settings.json`, defined the setting `AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage` which means Set to "`true`" to disable the default landing page shown for the root of the Azure Functions site.

**Ref:** [Configuration settings Information for Azure Functions Site.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Configuration-Settings)

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
"AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage": "true"
}
}
```

**Index.ts code:**

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from  "@azure/functions"
import { promises  as  fs } from  "fs"
import { resolve } from  "path"

const  httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async  function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

var  __dirname = "HttpTrigger1";
const  htmlPage = await  fs.readFile(resolve("./" + __dirname + "/index.html"), 'utf-8');

context.res = {
headers: {
"content-type":  "text/html"
},
body:  htmlPage
}
};

export  default  httpTrigger;
```

**Running the function locally:**

[image]

**Deployed to Azure and running in the cloud successfully:**

[image]

Comment: From what I can tell, this page seems to be running at /api/HttpTrigger1 rather than the root or index page as requested.

Comment: Yes @PaulSmith, we are replacing the Http Trigger API Response with the custom Page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to catch all of the paths (after disabling the homepage) by capturing the path as a variable:

```
"route": "{*restOfPath}"
```

in `function.json`.

I've done a [similar thing in Go](https://github.com/ivarprudnikov/cose-and-receipt-playground/blob/main/func-match-all-config/function.json)

The issue is that it overshadows other routes and the routing needs to be implemented in the code of the same catch-all function.