# Azure Function Proxy that works locally and on Azure

Tags: azure-functions, swagger-ui

I'm creating an Azure Function that will expose some API's.
.Net7, Azure Functions version 4, Isolated.

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": ""
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableProxies",
    "AZURE_FUNCTION_PROXY_DISABLE_LOCAL_CALL": "true"
  }
}
```

I've added the endpoints, added swagger and everything works fine.
Now I'm trying to replace welcome page with swagger ui.

I've tried two approaches:

1. Use proxy to route `/` to `/swagger/ui`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "swagger": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [ "GET" ],
        "route": "/"
      },
      "backendUri": "http://localhost:7071/swagger/ui"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use proxy to do a redirect to `swagger/ui`, so when someone opens `https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/` instead of seeing the welcome page he will be redirected to `https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "swagger": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [ "GET" ],
        "route": "/"
      },
      "responseOverrides": {
        "response.statusCode": "302",
        "response.headers.Location": "https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

both methods work fine, but only on localhost or on Azure. I can't get a single proxy to work on both environments.

To have it working on Azure I must use `https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui`, to have them working on localhost I must use `http://localhost:7071/swagger/ui`

So the question is: how to create a URL that can be used in proxy that will work both on localhost (when developing) and on azure (when deployed)

Answer (score 0):

Check if my understanding and below findings are helpful:

> both methods work fine, but only on localhost or on Azure. I can’t get a single proxy to work on both environments.

- It is working good in the local host with the keyword `/swagger/ui` as suffixed to the local base URL of function project even the `PROXY_DISABLE_LOCAL_CALL` is set to `true` but not working in the Azure.
- It is not replacing the default page with the Swagger UI.
- If this is the scenario, I found an SO Issue #[71059606](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059606/how-to-replace-home-page-in-azure-function-app-with-something-else) where the user is asking to replace the default Home Page of Azure Functions Site base URL and it is resolved with the configuration setting `"AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage": "true"`, that disables the default landing Home Page of Azure Function App both locally and in the Azure Cloud.
- And also, the response related to `swagger/ui` should be configured in the Body/Headers of that Http Trigger Function.